# Is circular pointers alright in this scenario?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have classes A, B and C.

A has members B and C.

C has data B wants to access.

I'm thinking of doing something like this, and would like to ask whether or not this is good design.

```
class A{
B* m_b;
C* m_c;
};

class B{
A* m_a; // so that i can get access to C->m_data
};

class C{
vector<Obj*> m_data;
}
```

How would you design class B?

Comment: There is no need to give `class B` a pointer to `A`, it can just hold a pointer to `C` and then there is no circular logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circular pointers are almost always a bad idea. You probably don't need access to `C->m_data` from the entire class `B`; just pass it as an argument to the `B` methods that need to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving enough info on what you actually want to achieve, but you don't need `m_a` (Hungarian notation, blah) to access data from `C`. You can directly have a `C` member inside `B`.

Also, what do you mean by *access data*? Note that accessing `C` elements, regardless of whether via getter methods or directly, breaks encapsulation.

> C has data B wants to access.

Are you sure `C` (or `A`) has to be a member of `B`? Seems like you can just pass it as a parameter.